# RGBDSLAM black screen, not receving data, not building model

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, openni, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to use RGBDSLAM to build a 3d model using a kinect sensor on a Turtlebot 2 running on Groovy and have so far been unable to get more than one image from the camera.

On the Turtlebot, I do: `roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch` and `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`

I am running RGBDSLAM on my own workstation. When I start RGBDSLAM (using 'rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam'), the GUI starts correctly and shows a black screen with two blue and red axes. I think hit the space bar and nothing happens, nothing is updated, even when I move the Turtlebot around. When I look at the terminal output for RGBDSLAM, I see the following (and it doesn't change at all):

```
[user]@[machine]:~$ rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam
Initializing Node...
[ INFO] [1373404458.387233301]: Connected to roscore
[ INFO] [1373404459.920681061]: Publishing latched (single publish will take longer, all topics are prepared)
[ INFO] [1373404460.197975256]: Listening to /camera/rgb/image_rect_color and /camera/depth_registered/image_rect
[ INFO] [1373404464.410408126]: Pause toggled to: false
```

Which shows that RGBDSLAM is not processing any data. I've checked to make sure openni.launch is producing nodes that publish to /camera/rgb/image_rect_color and /camera/depth_registered/image_rect and `rostopic echo /camera/rgb/image_rect_color` prints out an infinite series of numbers, as expected. The only other warning I receive is from the terminal that launched openni, which says (repeatedly):

```
[ WARN] [1373405079.849237881]: TF exception:
The tf tree is invalid because it contains a loop.
Frame /camera_depth_frame exists with parent /camera_rgb_frame.
Frame /camera_link exists with parent /camera_rgb_frame.
Frame /camera_rgb_frame exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /camera_rgb_optical_frame exists with parent /camera_rgb_frame.
Frame /wheel_left_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_link exists with parent /base_footprint.
Frame /wheel_right_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_footprint exists with parent /odom.
Frame /odom exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /camera_depth_optical_frame exists with parent /camera_depth_frame.
Frame /caster_back_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /caster_front_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /cliff_sensor_front_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /cliff_sensor_left_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /cliff_sensor_right_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /gyro_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /plate_bottom_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /plate_middle_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /plate_top_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_bottom_0_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_bottom_1_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_bottom_2_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_bottom_3_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_bottom_4_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_bottom_5_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_kinect_0_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_kinect_1_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_middle_0_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_middle_1_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_middle_2_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_middle_3_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_top_0_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_top_1_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_top_2_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /pole_top_3_link exists with parent /base_link.
```

What could be wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66947/rgbdslam-black-screen,-not-receving-data,-not-building-model/) by [JHarriman](https://answers.ros.org/users/5268/jharriman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't see the 2d images (rgb/depth) in rgbdslam's gui, my guess is that the transmission over the network (is it wifi?) is the problem.

Have a look at this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/37513/running-rgbdslam-over-multiple-machines/) and [this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/67626/how-to-use-kinect-data-to-run-rgbdslam-over-multiple-machines).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JHarriman](https://answers.ros.org/users/5268/jharriman/) on 2013-09-04**:
Yes, it was the WiFi connection that was the problem. The link to the synchronization policy was most helpful, and I solved the problem by creating buffering nodes. Thanks a lot for the links in the right direction!

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-26**:
Hi, I started working on rgbd slam with TurtleBot, ros hydro Ubunto 12.04 I followed this link:http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/ to install rgbd slam, and after I had a GUI window as the window exactly in this link,

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-26**:
with the two posts below: waiting for visual picture on topic waiting for depth image is topic there is no picture,

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-26**:
i think it was a problem with topics in launch files can some one help me and send to me the launch of openni+rgbdslam.launch openni.launch rgbdslam.launch